# Can't install kbcstorage library of exact version

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile

I developed application with python client for Keboola Storage [library](https://github.com/keboola/sapi-python-client) `kbcstorage==0.1.3`. The installation was performed via command:

`pip3 install git+https://github.com/keboola/sapi-python-client.git`

Now, when I am trying to build by docker image, I am not able to install version `0.1.3`, only `0.1.4.dev5+g8c2bb29`. How can I specify the version to install `0.1.3` ? I used to install packages using:

`pip3 install mypkg==version`

but here it is not possible. Could anybody help me, how to get version `0.1.3` via requirements?

I am using `python:3.6-alpine3.7` image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add version by using `git+https://github.com/keboola/sapi-python-client.git@0.1.3`.